# Rails 2.3.11 DateTime BigDecimal Precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a project in Ruby on Rails running Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.2

I have some unit tests that read data from a database, specifically a date time column for two consecutive items which are supposed to be 24 hours apart. In one test I am setting the datetime for item 2 equal to that of item 1.

When I do an assert to make sure the two values are equal, the test works fine under rails 2.3.2. When I upgrade to rails 2.3.11, the tests fails showing that the difference between the two times to be off with the following error:

```
<Thu, 01 Jan 2009 06:00:00 CST -06:00> expected but was
<Thu, 01 Jan 2009 05:59:59 CST -06:00>.
```

There seems to be an issue with floating point conversions in the two version of rails. How can I account for the floating point issue?

Comment: In your title you say Rails 2.3.11, but in your question you say 2.3.5, which is it?

Comment: What are the values as stored in the database? You should be able to replicate your test on `RAILS_ENV=test script/console` and then inspect the actual DB values using a SQL shell. Also are you using `DateTime#advance` to adjust your values or some other method?

Comment: I'm sure that the database is using a DateTime data type for the column. In order to adjust the values, I am using Time.at(seconds) to create the updated value and then setting the time variable to the gotten value.

Comment: Perhaps the Time mathematics have changes between Rails iterations. Can you post the code snippet used for the test?

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me too, and I ended up doing this:

```
datetime.should be_a(Datetime) # maybe unnecessary
datetime.to_s.should == expected_datetime.to_s
```